# My program keeps throwing IO exception after reading from binary file

Tags: java, file-io, bluej

I have taken in a text file and converted it into a binary by writing the objects to a binary file, then i am attempting to read from the binary file, which works all the way through till the last record and then it throws the IO exception and never gets to my last print statement.

Below is my code that is triggering the error

```
    try
    {
        ObjectInputStream objinputStream2 = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("binaryFile"));
        for (int run = 0; run<count;count++)
        {
            Record readone = (Record) objinputStream2.readObject();
            System.out.print(readone); 
            System.out.println("");

        }
        System.out.println("Reading completed for all" + count + " records. ");
       // objinputStream2.close();
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e){ // Catches object

        System.out.println("Sorry File not found"); // Error Message       
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){ // Catches object
        System.out.println("Sorry class not found"); // Error Message
    }
    catch(IOException e){ // Catches object
        System.out.println("Problem with file output."); // Error Message
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

any help is appreciated

Stack trace:

```
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:730)
```

Comment: edit the question to provide us the stacktrace

Comment: How is `count` being populated?  You may have fewer records in the file than you think.

Comment: Include the *full* exception. Right now, you're only providing the stack trace, not the full exception.

Comment: count is being populated by a while statement: 
while(inputStream.hasNext())

Comment: That was it, thank you guys! I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rethink the loop condition: `for (int run = 0; run<count;count++)`.

Neither `run` nor `count` are modified inside the loop, so it will run forever (until you try to read a record from your file and an `Exception` occurs).

I think it should be something like:

```
int count = 0;
for (int run = 0; run<numberOfRecordsInFile; run++)
{
    Record readone = (Record) objinputStream2.readObject();
    System.out.print(readone); 
    System.out.println("");
    count++;
}
System.out.println("Reading completed for all" + count + " records. ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
for (int run = 0; run<count;count++)
```

needs to be:

```
for (int run = 0; run<count;run++)
```

Each time it runs, it tries to grab more lines than it can, because run will always be less than count the way you have it written.